# Hibernate SQLQuery (Not enough values for host variable)

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlanywhere

We're using Hibernate with Sybase Anywhere 12 and experience a problem with a query on a view using `SQLQuery`.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(" SELECT * FROM myview WHERE x = :x AND y IN (:y) ");
query.setParameter("x", "z1234");
query.setParameterList("y", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
query.setReadOnly(true);
query.addEntity(ClassX.class);
List result = query.list();
```

The query fails after restarting the database and *only* one time. If we're executing the same query a second time with the same parameters, it's running smoothly.

The view is based on a table and another view based on two tables. These tables does have triggers. Just in case this might be the source for our problem, but it does not make sence to me since I did debug down to `Connection#prepareStatement(...)` where the `SQLException` occured.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Not enough values for host variables
        at sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method) ~[sajdbc4.jar:na]
        at sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IConnection.prepareStatement(IConnection.java:599) ~[sajdbc4.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:125) ~[com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc-1.1.0.1.jar:na]
        at $Proxy104.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
```

Any ideas?

---

```
10:16:33.851 WARN  [http-9443-2] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions[233] - SQL Error: -188, SQLState: 07002
10:16:33.851 ERROR [http-9443-2] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions[234] - [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Nicht genügend Werte für Hostvariablen
```

---

References: [Sybase Docs](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/saerrors_en11/errm188.html)

Comment: Sybase docs says that ="You have not provided enough host variables for either the number of bind variables, or the command, or the number of select list items." Please review your inputs and binds

Comment: Thanks. I did read the Sybase docs. :-) This would make sence if `PreparedStatement#executeQuery()` would throw that `SQLException` and not `Connection#prepareStatement(sqlQuery)` whereas `sqlQuery` is equals `SELECT * FROM myview WHERE x = ? AND y IN (?, ?, ?, ?)`.  At that point no parameters are passed or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the source of my problem. `myview` did have a warning symbol in Sybase Central. `myview` is based on another view which was dropped and created again. Therefore, `myview` has required a recompile.

**However**, the SQL Code of the thrown`SQLException` is wrong and leads into a wrong direction finding the source of the problem. `Connection#prepareStatement(sqlQuery)` does not pass any parameters.